# Jenkins declarative pipeline - User input parameters

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I've looked for some example of user input parameters using Jenkins declarative pipeline, however all the examples are using the scripted pipelines. Here is a sample of code I'm trying to get working:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                 input id: 'test', message: 'Hello', parameters: [string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'myparam')]
                 sh "echo ${env}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to work out how I can access the **myparam** variable, it would be great if someone could help me out.
Thanks

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 17):

When using *input*, it is very important to use *agent none* on the global pipeline level, and assign agents to individual stages. Put the *input* procedures in a separate stage that also uses *agent none*. If you allocate an agent node for the input stage, that agent executor will remain reserved by this build until a user continues or aborts the build process.

This example should help with using the Input:

```
def approvalMap             // collect data from approval step

pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            agent none
            steps {
             
                timeout(60) {                // timeout waiting for input after 60 minutes
                    script {
                        // capture the approval details in approvalMap. 
                         approvalMap = input 
                                        id: 'test', 
                                        message: 'Hello', 
                                        ok: 'Proceed?', 
                                        parameters: [
                                            choice(
                                                choices: 'apple\npear\norange', 
                                                description: 'Select a fruit for this build', 
                                                name: 'FRUIT'
                                            ), 
                                            string(
                                                defaultValue: '', 
                                                description: '', 
                                                name: 'myparam'
                                            )
                                        ], 
                                        submitter: 'user1,user2,group1', 
                                        submitterParameter: 'APPROVER'
                                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Stage 2') {
            agent any

            steps {
                // print the details gathered from the approval
                echo "This build was approved by: ${approvalMap['APPROVER']}"
                echo "This build is brought to you today by the fruit: ${approvalMap['FRUIT']}"
                echo "This is myparam: ${approvalMap['myparam']}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the input function returns, if it only has a single parameter to return, it returns that value directly. If there are multiple parameters in the input, it returns a map (hash, dictionary), of the values. To capture this value we have to drop to groovy scripting.

It is good practice to wrap your input code in a timeout step so that build don't remain in an unresolved state for an extended time.

Comment: Did this help with your problem?

Comment: "It is good practice to wrap your input code in a timeout step so that build don't remain in an unresolved state for an extended time." You don't need to worry about it if you cancel running builds of the same job everytime your build run.

To achieve that you can use following script (as shared library): https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/cancel-builds-same-job.groovy